# Change button background color and save older background

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to change my button background color to Red.

I try this `button.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);` but button gets bigger, then I try this `button.BackgroundTintList = (ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Red));` and works well.

But after that I need to put background button as before and I can't do that. I have another button with same background and try to copy from there using this

`Button anotherButton = _v.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt_anotherButton);
button.Background = anotherButton.Background;`

But instead of putting anotherButton background equals to button background, does the opposite and both button became Red.

Anyone could help?

Comment: You can save the previous color . Or you can use a Selector drawable for multiple states.

Comment: I'm trying save previous background but I can't do that.
I have this `Drawable dr = button.Background;` and then put dr as bacground but keeps red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @hichame has said, your button is not getting bigger. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043867/why-button-gets-bigger-when-the-background-is-set-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942357/button-gets-bigger-when-background-is-set-how-to-make-it-small/48980948#48980948) to understand why your button looks like bigger.

About the button's color, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471998/8632294) use `android.R.drawable.btn_default`:

```
button.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonDefault);
```

to reset your button. But, the result is not like the origin button.

---

Finally, I get the default button's color :`#D6D7D7`.

You can use this value to reset your button's color to default:

`button.Background.SetTintList(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.ParseColor("#D6D7D7")));`

### Update:

After read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756195/8632294) answer, I find a solution, you need use `AppCompatButton`, install [Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/), use it in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/bt1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/bt2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use `SupportBackgroundTintList` in your `MainActivity`( also that is why your return value is null):

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,View.IOnClickListener
{
    AppCompatButton bt1;
    ColorStateList backgroundTintList;
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        bt1.SupportBackgroundTintList=(backgroundTintList);
        //bt1.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonDefault);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        
        bt1 = FindViewById<AppCompatButton>(Resource.Id.bt1);
        AppCompatButton bt2 = FindViewById<AppCompatButton>(Resource.Id.bt2);
       
        backgroundTintList = bt2.SupportBackgroundTintList;

        bt1.SupportBackgroundTintList=ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Red);

        bt2.SetOnClickListener(this); 
       
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try this `button.Background.SetTintList(ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.ParseColor("#D6D7D7")));` and it works.

Now I have this [code](https://pastebin.com/KcXx7wra) and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not getting bigger but it is getting the padding of the default Android button. 
You have to set the tint to not modify the size of your background settings and you can do it by:

```
var previousTint = button.BackgroundTintList;
button.Background.SetTint (Color.HoloRedDark);
```

And once done, set back the previous tint.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This var previousTint = button.BackgroundTintList; returns null. Rigth now I have this: https://pastebin.com/du3jVfuL